# Can I give computer accounts access to delete themselves?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to have a scheduled task running in the local system context on the local computer which deletes its own computer account from AD.

Can I give computer objects access to delete themselves?

I have all my computers under one top level OU. Which specific ACLs would I need to set on this OU to allow computers inside it to delete themselves (and only themselves).

Comment: Hmm... This is kind of strange. May I ask why you're doing this?

Comment: As part of an auto scaling clean up routine. Just want to know if I can give computers accounts this specific access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It's possible.  Just grant SELF the "Delete" permission on the computer objects. This means computer accounts will have permissions to delete their own computer objects. You may also require "Delete Subtree" if the computer account has child objects, but they usually do not have child objects.

This of course means that computer's trust relationship with the domain is broken, but you already knew that.